# Jquery datatable displayed with low brightness in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JQuery DataTable in Inter Explorer 11**

[image]

**JQuery DataTable in Chrome**
[image]

I am new to JQuery and learning the things one by one. I am facing a couple of issues with JQuery DataTable.

1. The JQuery DataTable is not properly rendered. It's having low
   brightness in IE11. But the same DataTable is rendered with required brightness in Chrome and Firefox. You can see the difference in the pictures that I have uploaded(the first one is for IE and the second one for chrome).
2. In IE11, the DataTable is missing the vertical and horizontal scroll
   bars, but the same thing is working perfectly in chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

I am initializing the main DataTable with the following piece of code:

```
//DataTables aplies style and behavior to <table>
    var table = $('#CaseLkupTable').DataTable({
        "scrollY": 315, // inconsistent IE7/other
        "scrollX": true,
        "searching": false,
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "orderable": false,
            'responsive': true
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Most likely css-problem, you might have some filter-property in css which will only affect IE, others will ignore it. Check that out.

Comment: @Esko, Thanks for the response. I have verified. There is one common CSS file. The weird part is that the similar datatable(developed for different screen) is rendered properly in IE11. The only difference is that my datatable has many dynamic nested datatales inside it. Any particular CSS property that I need look into?

Comment: One more thing is that why the horizontal and vertical scrollbars are not working? Any clue on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason. The table is disabled by some of the code.Weirdly the disabling code is executed in IE only. So, table was working fine after I removed the disabling JavaScript code.